# Visual Studio scripting error when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I try to debug with Visual Studio 2017 I see scripting errors like the following:

[image]

"An error has occurred in the script on this page."

There are various errors in various scripts that I have to click though.

I tried clearing Internet Explorer out completely, cookies, temp files, everything. This only started after a recent update to VS2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upgrade Internet Explorer to 11

Comment: I did think about that, but IE11 won't install on my computer for some reason (Windows 7). It was fine until the latest update.

Comment: I have solved this problem like i said, i think latest update doesn't support under version of IE11 @shogged

Comment: I'll try to re-install it again.

Comment: I can't install IE11 either, it fails every time. I spent a long time trying to fix it a few years ago.

Comment: I managed to install IE, after some hard core diagnostics. VS2017 works fine now. Nice of them not to warn me that the update was incompatible with my system.

Answer (score 0):

**WebBrowser**>> Properties **ScriptErrorsSuppressed** set it **True**

Comment: More details please? I can't upgrade to IE11 either, so I need to disable the message somehow.

Comment: This answer concerns the WebBrowser control for WinForms, NOT any Internet Explorer setting. Completely unrelated to the question!